# What is Dowork() in background worker exactly do?

Tags: wpf, background, worker

I have a confusing that: in every single demo of background worker. they put `Thread.Sleep();` in this method to simulate for a long length of operation. But if I have a operation of import data from database to datatable, and I called this method: importData(). and I replace `Thread.Sleep();` by it. That is mean it will be import for 100 time? Thanks for your answer.

```
 void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoWork` is the main event of a background worker. It means that the work it has to do in the background will be done in that event.

If you put your `ImportData()` method is in a `for-loop`, then yes your data will be importet 100 times, or whatever variable you add instead of 100.

But you don't need to do your work in a `for-loop`, just skip the `for-loop` part and do the `ImportData()` part

Remarks from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This event is raised when you call the RunWorkerAsync method. This is
>   where you start the operation that performs the potentially
>   time-consuming work.
>
> Your code in the DoWork event handler should periodically check the
>   CancellationPending property value and abort the operation if it is
>   true. When this occurs, you can set the Cancel flag of
>   System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs to true, and the Cancelled flag
>   of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs in your
>   RunWorkerCompleted event handler will be set to true.

Comment: if I do not put it in loop. how number of percentages still count without (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i) ? please explain to me, i just faced it for the first time.

Comment: @PhanThếKhương The percentage you have to provide yours self. Let's assume you are doing 12 time consuming operations, then you have to provide 100/12 after each operation. If only one operation then it doesn't make sense with a percentage.

Comment: btw, if i want to add progress bar. how should i do it? create a new control user or adding directly to main window?

Comment: @PhanThếKhương: I would say that's a new question, but anyway have a look at this tutorial http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/